# Centre Ul on footer

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I'm trying to center my two lists one below the other on my footer, but I can't.
My contents are always arranged to the right or left, I don't know why does anyone have an idea?
    here I put the test

https://codepen.io/ta_io/pen/oNNZpyE

```
footer {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
}

footer ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 12px 70px;
}

footer li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-color: saddlebrown;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer li {
  float: left;
}
footer li a {
  padding: 20px 20px;
}
footer .menu {
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  max-height: none;
}

footer .menu2 {
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  max-height: none;
}
```

Comment: Some of the HTML code would help too

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:flex` on `footer` together with `justify-content:center`.

In the bellow snippet they do not 'fit' inside the footer to stay side-by-side, but on a bigger screen, they will fit.

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;

  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  transition: opacity 0.8s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s ease 0s;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}
footer {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  position: fixed;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

footer ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 12px 70px;
}

footer li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-color: saddlebrown;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer li {
  float: left;
}
footer li a {
  padding: 20px 20px;
}
footer .menu {
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  max-height: none;
}

footer .menu2 {
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  max-height: none;
}
```

```html
 <footer>
        
         
   
            <ul class="menu2" >
    <li><a  style="background-color: red" href="#work">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a style="background-color: red" href="#about">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a style="background-color: red" href="#careers">link 3</a></li>
                <li><a style="background-color: red" href="#careers">link 4</a></li>
  
  </ul>
            
            <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">FB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">TW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">G</a></li>
  
  </ul> 
           
                

        </footer>
```